# How to forcefully call a base method from child

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance, parent-child

I have multiple classes that inherit an abstract class. I have made one method in the base class which is generic for all the child classes. I want all the child classes to compulsorily call that method, else compile error should be shown.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: could you show your current code?

Comment: Hard to guess without code, but I can't think of a compiler error for _not calling a method_.

Comment: When should the method be called? If it should be called during creation, the base class should only expose the required constructor. Otherwise the logic should be reversed where the base class has the exposed method, which calls an abstract (protected) method that all inheritors should implement.

Comment: [base](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx) might help

Comment: If all child classes must call this method anyway, why can't you call it in the base class?

Comment: In non abstract class (eg. your base class), you can still use `abstract` to define that method needs to be filled.

Comment: @AleksandarToplek You can introduce `abstract` members (like methods) __only__ in a class which is `abstract`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the call in the base class constructor. Any derived object *must* call the base class constructor so you are guaranteed that the mandatory method is always called upon object creation:

```
public abstract class Base
{
     protected Base()
     {
         //....
         mandatoryMethod();
     }

     private void mandatoryMethod() { ... }

     public abstract Foo Frob();
}

public class Derived: Base
{
     public Derived(....)
     {
         //new Base() will have been called when execution reaches this point.
     }

     public override Foo Frob() { ... }
}
```

Of course this has some limitations:

1. If `MandatoryMethod` needs to be called after `Derived`'s constructor has finished running, this will not work.
2. If your hardly defined requirement "compulsory call" means calling `MandatoryMethod` before calling any `Derived` method, this will not work and there is no way you could enforce this. Your only option is code review if you own the code of all consumers or changing the requirement if you don't.

The compiler's job is to compile *legal* code and disallow *illegal* code. There is nothing illegal about not calling from `Derived` any given method defined in `Base`; that is a logic need in your application, not a language requirement. You can not enforce this with the compiler, the closest you can get is using the constructor solution where the compiler does guarantee that `MandatoryMethod` will in fact always be called when constructing a `Derived` object.

Comment: An instance constructor (your `public Base()`) of an `abstract` class should not be public. Making it public is a bit confusing since you cannot say `new Base()` anywhere, the only use for the constructor is chaining it from deriving classes, so it is normal to say `protected Base()` in this case.